# maximum and minimum allowed memory

Tags: c#, .net

Can you point me to an API or method used to retrieve the maximum and allowed minimum video graphics memory of my local system ? I have looked into WMI and found none to help me with this. For my laptop it is reported a range of 8-256 MB, I can only get 256. Where is that 8 coming from ? Please ask if you think my question is unreal.

Comment: How did you get this "8" number?

Answer (score 0):

unless you are trying to get the hardware spec related to graphic.
I don't think its practical to ask the OS about the min and max, as they can use virtual mem/mem-management to dymanically adjust that as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 8 is the minimum value required so that video card will be able to display a GUI.